# Linksys router shows "Unsecured" connection with Windows 8

Tags: windows, laptop, security

I have a new Lenovo laptop running Windows 8 and a Linksys wireless router.

While using it, the wireless notified me that it was not connected.  Tried unplugging and replugging modem.  Now it reports that it's connected—but with a little exclamation mark that says

> Security: Unsecured
>   Type: 802.11g

Is this a safe connection? If not, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a safe connection?

It is not secure, you are trying to connect, to an unencrypted wireless connection.

> What should I do to fix?

You should configure the security of the wireless network your trying to connect to per the manual of the router/modem you are trying to connect to.